# Nodejs subscribe button redirects me to 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

When I click the subscribe button it redirects my page to `127.0.0.1` and nothing appears in `console.log`. Why is that

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Abonelik</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
         crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
         integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="signin.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="parent-wrapper">
         <span class="close-btn glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
         <div class="subscribe-wrapper">
            <h4>Abone Olun</h4>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
               <input type="text" name="fname" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Adınız">
               <input type="text" name="lname" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Soyadınız">
               <input type="email" name="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Mail Adresiniz">
               <button type="submit">Abone Ol</button>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Nodejs

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.get("subs", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    const mail = req.body.email;
    const ilkad = req.body.fname;
    const soyad = req.body.lname;
    console.log(fname, lname, email);
    const data = {
        members: [{
            email_address: mail,
            status: "Subscribed",
            merge_fields: {
                FNAME: fname,
                LNAME: lname,
            }
        }]
    };
    const jData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url = "https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/";
    const option = {
        method: "post",
        auth: ""
    };
    const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {
        response.on("data", function() {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
    request.write(jData);
    request.end();
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server Çevrimiçi");
});
```

I just wanted to apply the subscribe button a function to send data to the hyper terminal when the user logs mail name surname etc. but when I click it redirects me to 127.0.0.1 which is local folder. and I am almost sure that there is something wrong between app.get and form direction but I don't know how to solve this problem. I know it is a long post sorry for that but I really appreciate some help. thank you.

Comment: Side note: You don't need the `type="submit"` on `<button type="submit">Abone Ol</button>`. The *default* `type` of `button` elements is `"submit"`.

Comment: `console.log(mail, ilkad, soyad);`  try this

Comment: thanks but it didn't work :(

Comment: Please share your code via `Github` if possible

Comment: thank you :) i finally figured it what out the loose end in my code. it is because of the missing redirect path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the wrong variables. Since you do this:

```
const mail = req.body.email;
const ilkad = req.body.fname;
const soyad = req.body.lname;
```

you should print the data from request by:

```
console.log(ilkad, soyad, email);
```

Also, a good practice is using the object destructuring like this:

```
const {email, fname, lname} = req.body
```

and then use:

```
console.log(fname, lname, email);
```

Comment: thanks for effort but it didn't work. page still redirects me to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Try using res.redirect(path), where path is the page you want to redirect the user.